# How do you convert 'lectulus' from a noun to an adjective?

Tags: grammar-choice, adjective

I'm thinking that a houseguest who stays on your couch should be something like *hospes lectuli.* But that sounds more like a guest invited by your couch, which is silly. In my non-expert understanding of how Latin normally works, this kind of construction should call for an adjective. But all I know is the noun *lectulus.* How could I make that into an adjective so that it clearly modifies *hospes*?

Comment: *Lectulus* means a little bed.  Make it a bigger bed, for starters.

Comment: @Hugh It's a couch. They aren't big.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes -That's not the problem. It's impossible to form an adjective from lectulus.

Comment: How about adding ''-alis,'' so ''lectulalis''?

Comment: Wouldn't we expect to see a simple genitive of description in Latin? That is to say, isn't hospes lectuli idiomatically correct?

Comment: Well, if you want to use a Greek root and completely confuse modern readers, just write "clinicalis"!

Answer (score 7):

You could use **lectualis** or **lectuarius**, "of or belonging to the bed". Lewis & Short:

> lectŭālis, e, adj. [2. lectus], of or belonging to the bed: "morbus", which confines one to his bed, Spart. Hadr. 23 dub. (al. letalis).

> lectŭārĭus, a, um, adj. [id.], of or belonging to the bed, bed- (late Lat.): "lectuaria (lecticaria) sindon", Non. 537, 21.

But, in this case, perhaps an adjective from a verb might be your best option, like the participle **pernoctans**, from *pernocto* "stay the night".

P.S. Using a noun in the genitive is usually a very natural option in Latin, so I think **lecti** would be a good choice. The genitive can be used to express many other relations than real possession; it can also express a vague relationship like "belonging to, having to do with".

Comment: *Pernoctare* is a great verb for this context. The personal forms and the future participle are also useful in some situations.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: Such as on Latin dating apps?

Comment: Not really what I had in mind but, true, that too. Perhaps our site ought to have a question about dating or other apps where Latin is in use. (I was thinking of something like: *Amicus meus pernoctaturus mecum cenat.*)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: Well, well. Your friend dines with you intending to stay the night? Interesting!

Answer (score 5):

In your question you have used the genitive, and *'lecti'* of a bed may be your best option. Or *'lectuli.'*

It's almost impossible to find an adjective from any of the words for bed; and those two which can form adjectives imply the guest is sick or in child-birth. *Lectus, torus, cubile, stratum* (often in plural) or even *clinus, tectus* and *grabatus.*

> *contubernalis,* a couch fellow.

sounded promising, but it's the (ten) men who shared a tent in the army.

In general, adjectives from nouns are difficult;  it is much easier to form adjectives from verbs:

> *cubans:* present participle of *cubo:* lie down,

Hospitality is best expressed by:

***Hospitio aliquem excipere*** where *'aliquem'* stands for any guest.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something more literally similar to English, here is a suggestion.
I want to get an adjective derived from "couch" and a noun for "surfer", as I find that to be the best [Latin equivalent of English noun adjuncts](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7298/79).

A couple of words for a couch come to mind after consulting dictionaries: *lectus, lectulus, torus, stibadium, grabatus, grabatulus*.
If you want to refer to someone who comes to sleep on your couch rather than in your bed, I would avoid the ones that also stand for a bed (*lectus, lectulus, grabatus*).
I think *torus* is also way too general and hard to parse as a couch.
The least prone to misunderstanding seems to be *stibadium*, a seat or a couch.

I don't think we should be trying to translate "surfer" in a way that connects to surfing; I am not aware of a Latin word for it, and it would lead to quite a confusing result.
I would be badly confused with the English term "couch surfer" too if I had not heard it before.
There are many different directions to go: *hospes* (guest), *amicus* (friend), *viator* (traveller).
If this is a person who travels the world and sleeps on sofas, then I think *viator* works best.
If the point of view is that of a couch-owner, then perhaps *hospes*.

So my suggestion would be ***viator/hospes stibadialis***, depending on the point of view.
If you use this, be prepared for your audience needing to take some time to parse it unless you introduce it well.
In a suitable contest this would make a decent expression.