# How do you say "Forum Friends" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, declension

In English, if you have people you are friends with from a forum (online or otherwise), you could call them "forum friends". How would you say this in Latin? Can you decline *forum* as a genitive like *amicī forī*, or would that be more like saying they are friends of the forum itself? Would you use ablative case instead with a preposition?

**Edit:** I did some search and found this post regarding [using a noun as an adjective](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/how-do-you-convert-a-noun-to-an-adjective-in-latin), which got me thinking that there might be an adjective that means "associated with the forum" or similar.

There is the word [circumforaneus](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/circumforaneus), which has the following meanings:

> itinerant, that travels to market; of/connected with business of/around forum

With this adjective, I could do something like:

> Amici Circumforanei

Would this make sense?

Answer (score 5):

'X friends', in English, I think can reasonably be reinterpreted as 'friends from X', and this suggests the Latin ***amici de foro***, ***amici a foro*** or ***amici e foro***. I'll leave it to someone with a little more knowledge of the three different prepositions to suggest which fits best here.

Using an adjective seems wrong to me, since being related to the forum isn't a property of your friends from the forum (any more than my school friends are scholastic, or work friends are... worky?).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the choice of *de*? I tried to look into *de*, *ex*, and *ab*, and I ended up with no clear preference in this kind of use.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I didn't put a lot of thought into it, and don't have access to a dictionary other than Wiktionary, so don't want to give an impression of greater certainty than I have. Having said that, *ex* definitely sounds wrong to me since there is no movement out of the forum involved.

Comment: The preposition *ex* is not solely for movement; for example, *e marmore factus* is "made of marble". All these three prepositions have quite wide ranges of meanings. It might well be that *de* is the best, but I don't have a clear opinion yet.